# How does the use of a definite article change the meaning of following sentences?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-articles

1. My niece is in hospital.
2. My niece is in the hospital.

Both the sentences look good to me. Is there any difference between the two sentences?

Although I know the difference but the real question is how would the use of article 'the' create that difference? How would you justify that?

As far as I have learned, the first sentence means that my niece is in hospital as a patient, whereas the second sentence means that my niece is in the hospital, but not necessarily as a patient. How does 'the' account for this difference between the meanings?

Comment: The answer changes based on whether this is BrE or AmE.  In AmE we never say *in hospital* whether they're a patient or no.  In AmE you're a patient if you're "***in*** *the hospital*" and you're visiting if you're ***at*** *the hospital*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*in hospital* = British; *in the hospital* = U.S.

(They mean the same thing, each in its respective milieu.)

Answer (score -4):

both sentence tells us the same meaning

Comment: You don't have to write an answer if that's already written by another user.